# ng-include not loading partial view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I'm currently working on a project, that I've got some problems with. Whatever I try to do, ng-include can't load a partial view I have in another folder.

I want to load `view.html` file in pagination folder. My file is in the folder which is on the same level that pagination folder.

Here's my site view fragment

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-6" id="NEWS">
    <div class="well" ng-repeat="info in news">
      <p>
        {{info.description}}
      </p>
    </div>
    <ng-include src="'/pagination/view.html'"></ng-include>
  </div>
</div>
```

My `view.html` has a single `caption test`  for testing purpose.

I also tried using this code:

```
<div ng-include src=....
<div ng-include="....
<ng-include src="'../pagination/view.html".
```

Nothing seems to work. Someone knows what is the problem about?

Comment: Why not creating a directory with a templateUrl and including that directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My file is in the folder which is on the same level that pagination folder.

You're propably passing a wrong path for the html template.

You have to refer to your template directory as if you're writing in your `index.html` file. So no matter which html template the `ng-include` directive exists you have to give it the path as if your root is the place where index.html exists.

Also try to avoid using '/' before the path.

e.g.

Suppose you're having the following folder tree:

---index.html

---/templates/app.html

---/tempates/pagination/view.html

In case you're trying to include the `view.html` in your `app.html` then you would do it like this:

```
<ng-include src="'templates/pagination/view.html'"></ng-include>
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this type error are

1. passing a wrong path for the html template.
2. Passing path is not in lower case .
   In angularJS all reference path must be in lower case like

```
<div ng-include="'/content/patna/partials/skive/test-partial.html'"></div>
```